# add if statement in flutter based on easy_localization user language

Tags: flutter, if-statement, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies, flutter-localizations

i'm traying to add if statement in flutter based on easy_localization chosen language

here is the code

```
  Future<bool> handleFcmSubscribtion() async {
    final SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _subscription = sp.getBool('subscribed') ?? true;
    if (_subscription == true && Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode == 'es') {
      _fcm.subscribeToTopic(subscriptionTopic);
      debugPrint('subscribed');
    } else {
      _fcm.unsubscribeFromTopic(subscriptionTopic);
      debugPrint('unsubscribed');
    }

    return _subscription;
  }
```

the problem is when i add && Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode == 'es'
i get Undefined name 'context' i can't figure it out how to use it here, I'm just start with flutter sorry
my target is, i will add firebase topic depend on user chosen lang on this step

Comment: From where are you calling the method and what is the value of context? Try adding ContextBuilder as a parameter of your method and pass your current context that way.

Answer (score 1):

where is passed this code ?
you need call it valid context